# Return value of hereAPI router in metres?

Tags: here-api, here-routing

We're currently investigating in the HERE Routing API v8 but can't really determine what the actual result consists of when units is set to metric.

Example result:

```
"summary": {
  "duration": 1670,
  "length": 12865,
  "baseDuration": 1506
},
"transport": {
  "mode": "truck"
}
```

Would the length be in metres perhaps? And what about the duration? Is that in seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the following parameters along with their units of measurement

1. duration:
   required
   integer (Duration)
   Duration in seconds.
2. length :
   required
   integer (Distance) >= 0
   Distance in meters.                                                                       For more information please refer to the following [API Reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/api-reference-swagger.html)